# Documentation / Explination for {...this.props}

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to figure out what `<ReactiveElement {...this.props} />` is in React. What I assume it does is provides a Reactive Element with the props of the parent, essentially shorthand for `ReactiveElement(this.props)`. Or is it just example code? I'm very confused and I can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [JSX Spread Attributes](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html#spread-attributes): "The properties of the object that you pass in are copied onto the component's props. You can use this multiple times or combine it with other attributes. The specification order is important. Later attributes override previous ones."

It's inspired by the [spread operator in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [Object Rest/Spread Properties ES7 proposal](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread#readme).

Example:

```
var props = {
  foo: x,
  bar: y
};
var component = <Component {...props} />;
```

is equivalent to:

```
var component = <Component foo={x} bar={y} />;
```

You can override some of the values if you want:

```
<Component {...props} foo={'some other value'} />;
```

Comment: GREAT! Thank you so much! Had no clue what to search for `...` won't show up in search!

Comment: @ThomasReggi Yeah, some things are impossible to search for, the search engines should be better at searching for random characters. I knew what to search for only because I knew how this operator is named in ES6. I'm glad it helped.